# images are not rendering on website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

ive looked at other answers and none of them seemed to work which is why i decided to re-ask the question and show you guy my code so you can help me so here it is :

```js
function searchForm() {
 var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
 var search = document.getElementById('GIF-search').value;
 var content = document.getElementById('content')


 var xhr = $.get("http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=" + search + "&api_key=api");
 xhr.done(function(data) {
  var image = data; 
  var GIF = image['data'][0]['embed_url'];

  var GIF_image = document.createElement('img');
  GIF_image.setAttribute('src', GIF);
  GIF_image.setAttribue('id', 'GIF');

  content.appendChild(GIF_image)




 });
}
var searchGIF = document.getElementById('search_GIF')
searchGIF.addEventListener('click', searchForm, false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>GIF viewer</title>
 <style type="text/css">
  #content {
   width: 100%
  }
  img {
   width: 250px;
   height: 250px
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="Search">
 <input type="text" name="" id="GIF-search">
 <button id="search_GIF">Search GIFs</button>
</div>
<div id="content"></div>
 <script src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
 <script src="GIFsearch.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

my problem here is that im getting a blank image on my site can anyone explain why this is happening and how i can fix it so it will actually show the GIF?

btw i know in the $.get("http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=" + search + "&api_key=api"); the apikey in not valid (this is on purpose);

Comment: Have you included jQuery in your code?

Comment: yeah i have included jquery

Comment: `"ReferenceError: $ is not defined"` you need to include jQuery in your snippet.

Comment: when i run it i get no error just an empty image

Comment: Please post a jsfiddle with some working api key. You can change the api key later..

Comment: i will do that know

Comment: Have you tried console.log() 'ing the various variables (data, and GIF) to see what their values are?

Comment: yeah they are links to the images on giphy

Comment: and data is the JSON

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

1. There was no jQuery in jsfiddle. Make sure you have it in your code.
2. Make `https://` api call if your page is using `https://` protocol.
3. `setAttribute` when you are setting `id` has got a typo. Look carefully.
4. URL you are getting at `image['data'][0]['embed_url']` is not a image url but a webpage url. Try console log it and see. So you cant really set it as a src of some img tag. Find the correct image url and then proceed.